# Recuperar dados JSON via AJAX e PHP

Tags: php, ajax, json

Senhores, estou montando um sistema onde ele vai consultar uma API e mostrar os resultados dentro de DIVs. Porém estou parando neste resultado, somente pelo console.log não estou conseguindo jogar dentro das divs. 
Segue a imagem do retorno do JSON: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando consumir o JSON da seguinte maneira:

```
var url = 'https://allsportsapi.com/api/football/?met=H2H&APIkey=aafcadc8cb3f9937e6fb2576051b56ac980b9c342e99813b47ade59da2140522&firstTeamId=2616&secondTeamId=2617';
$.getJSON({
    type: "GET", 
    url: url,
    timeout: 3000,
    datatype: 'JSON',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("h2").html("Carregando..."); //Carregando
    },
    error: function() {
        $("h2").html("O servidor não conseguiu processar o pedido");
    },
    success: function(retorno) {
            // Interpretando retorno JSON...
            console.log(retorno);
            var clientes = retorno;
            // Listando cada cliente encontrado na lista...
            $.each(clientes,function(i, cliente){
                var item = "<p>"+cliente.event_home_team+"</p><p>"+cliente.event_away_team+"</p>";
                $("#retorno").append(item);
            });
                //Limpar Status de Carregando 
                $("h2").html("Carregado"); 
    } 
});
```

Para se encaixar no Layout: (mas preciso corrigir o retorno do JSON, pegando os resultados eu organizo as divs)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Muito Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 0):

**[RESOLVIDA]**

Depois de varias horas tentando entender onde estava errando, consegui resolver e ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
$.getJSON("https://allsportsapi.com/api/football/?met=H2H&APIkey=aafcadc8cb3f9937e6fb2576051b56ac980b9c342e99813b47ade59da2140522&firstTeamId=2616&secondTeamId=2617", function(data){
$.each(data, function (key, item) {
    $.each(item.H2H, function(key, value){

        away_team = value.event_away_team; //timeB
        event_home = value.event_home_team; //timeA



        $('.timeA').html(event_home);
        $('.timeB').html(away_team);

    })
});
```

})

Primeiro mandei um $.each percorrer o resultado, depois um novo $.each entrando no nó que desejaria!

Caso alguém passe pelo mesmo problema que eu, esta ai o resultado.

Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 0):

O problema do primeiro código acredito que era na função success, faltou converter de string para json:

```
success: function (retorno){
  cliente = JSON.parse(retorno);
}
```

Comment: Show, já consegui sim! Obrigado pela ajuda!